# Как остановить Timer в ACTION_UP?

Tags: android

Есть ракета, которая движется в определенную сторону при ACTION_DOWN(при зажиме) при помощи Timer, хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы пользователь нажимал на экран и ракета двигалась, но когда, он опускал палец, ракета сразу же останавливалась.
Вот код, который был написан, и в этом коде при ACTION_UP таймер останавливается, но на деле же он просто начинает конфликтовать уже со следующим таймером нажатия, как исправить?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(event.getY()>(Game.heightDisplay/2)) {
                timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 100);
            }
            else if(event.getY()<(Game.heightDisplay/2)) {
                timerTask2 = new MyTimerTask2();
                timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask2, 0, 100);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            timerTask.cancel();
            timerTask2.cancel();

            break;
    }


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
   class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        if(coordY >= 930) {
            coordY = 930;

        }
        else {
            coordY = coordY + 50;
        }
    }
}

class MyTimerTask2 extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        if(coordY <= 0) {
            coordY = 5;

        }
        else {
            coordY = coordY - 50;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что значит *начинает конфликтовать*?

Comment: Это значит, что одновременно существуют два таймера, один из которых пытается тянуть ракету вверх, другой тоже вверх и ракета летит в два раза быстрее и, возможно, дергается

Comment: @P.Ilyin, да, вы правы, он начинает двигаться в два раза быстрее, но у меня экран разделен на две половины, нажатие на которые задает различные направления ракеты, поэтому при нажатии на противоположную сторону, таймер одной половины и другой начинают конфликтовать,из-за чего ракета замирает на одном месте и дергается(то есть 2 таймера изменяют координаты ракеты на противоположные(+50 и -50, поэтому и дергается))

Comment: @En1q0d, а почему вы сами таймеры не останавливаете?.. Т.е. `timer.camcel();` `timer2.camvel();` помимо завершения таймерТасков?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, это просто я пробовал разные варианты(в этом случае без timer.cancel();), а так даже с timer.cancel() и timer2.cancel(); не работает.

Comment: @En1q0d, а этот случай вообще вызывается?.. Т.е. если вывести что-то в консоль из UP - оно там появится?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сделал лог, при ACTION_UP ничего не появляется, но если  return super.onTouchEvent(event); изменить на return true;, то лог срабатывает, но вылетает ошибка                                                             04-28 22:00:00.029 14507-14507/samsung.ru.spacex E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
04-28 22:00:00.029 14507-14507/samsung.ru.spacex E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
04-28 22:00:00.059 14507-14507/samsung.ru.spacex E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучшим решением будет завести один таймер, который будет существовать в течение всей игровой сессии, независимо от нажатий пользователя.
При этом у ракеты пускай будет переменная velocity (скорость). Когда пользователь нажимает на экран, устанавливайте velocity = 50, а когда убирает палец с экрана, velocity = 0. Таймер же всегда будет перемещать ракету на значение переменной velocity. Если velocity будет 50 - ракета будет двигаться, а елси 0, то стоять